# Change vertical unit in a LAS/Z file with PDAL

Tags: lidar, proj, units, pdal, vertical

I am using `pdal translate` to filter and transform some lidar files. One issue we have are the vertical units. Sometimes they are correctly specified, sometimes they are not, and sometimes they are missing - so for the US we determine the correct units by comparing with NED. We also have an override option for the user but automation is key,and this should be considered rare / last resort. The end result should have meters for the vertical units.

The last step in the pdal translate pipeline is to apply a reprojection, eg:

```
--filters.reprojection.out_srs="+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon=-90 +k_0=0.9996 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +units=m +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
```

There is often a datum change, and if the input is well-specified feet then the above does a good job of producing vertical meters output, although the units in the SRS are "empty" (only my code is reading this, so the final specified vertical units aren't as important as what the actual values are).

Okay, but what if we determine the input is feet? I can apply numeric correction quite easily using a filters.transformation.matrix (multiply Z by 0.3048) or I can use filters.projpipeline:

```
--filters.projpipeline.coord_op="+proj=pipeline +step +proj=unitconvert +z_out=m"
```

however, both of these modify the numeric values without changing the SRS vertical unit - so if the vertical unit was set properly to start with, the final reprojection re-applies the scale!

Is there a way to overrride the SRS's linear vertical unit in PDAL without actually changing the values? If so, if I detect feet, I can set it to "Feet" (so it is always set correctly) and then let the reprojection do the actual scaling.

---

One alternative would be to apply the auto vertical unit detection after the reprojection. The problem here is that we lose the ability to have a user manual override - because we don't know if the input is really in meters or feet and what the reprojection will do.